# ¿Cómo hago para que al cambiar de color, en la BD se guarde como ocupado o disponible?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Necesito ayuda para que al hacer click en cualquier habitación y se ponga rojo, no solo se guarde en una bd, pero no sé como hacer que llame a la bd. Ademas de que quiero que el color "**008000**" sea disponible y el color "**B40404**" sea ocupado.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tabla</title>
  <script>
    var color="";
    function change (elemento) {
      if(color=="#B40404")
      {
        elemento.style.backgroundColor=color="#008000";
      }else{
        elemento.style.backgroundColor=color="#B40404";
      }
    }
  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="style.css" media="screen, all" />
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Administración de habitaciones:</h1>

<table width="50%" class="medio" border="black" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 1</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 2</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 3</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="50%" border="black" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 5</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 6</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 7</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#008000" onclick="change(this);"><p>Habitación 8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Facturación</p></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Que BBDD?, ¿que campos tiene?, etc. Falta mucha información para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Lo siento, la bd no está creada, pero si la creara, se llamaría "habitacion", la tabla tendría campos como "n_habitacion y estado", ya que en n_habitacion pondría que habitación es y en estado, si está disponible o no.